# How do you type ~ on the iPhone's keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

The iPhone keyboard has support for typing characters like ¿ by selecting a similar character on the keyboard and holding the key for a short time. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to type a ~ character (a tilde). How does one do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On keyboard, press the <kbd>123</kbd> button to bring up numbers. From here press <kbd>#+=</kbd> to bring up more characters. <kbd>~</kbd> is the 4th from the left, second row.

Answered on an iPhone :D

Comment: So I'm just completely blind then. Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language of the keyboard. In the German keyboard it is the **third** from the left, second row. In the English keyboard also. And in the SwissGerman also, and in the Dutch also.